# ORACLE Database | remove tablespace with missing datafile

Tags: database, oracle

I mistakenly remove the datafiles before I drop the tablespace. But the tablespace occupy a large size space. I need to remove it, any method?

It occur:

```
DROP TABLESPACE abc;
```

*

```
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01116: error in opening database file 8
ORA-01110: data file 8: '/data/oradata/oracle/abc.dbf'
ORA-27041: unable to open file
Linux-x86_64 Error: 2: No such file or directory
Additional information: 3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can follow the steps given here in this [Oracle forum](https://community.oracle.com/thread/2313234?start=0&tstart=0):

> Follow the below steps : -
>
> 1) Shutdown abort
>
> 2) sqlplus sys/xxx as sysdba
>
> 3) Alter database mount
>
> 4) alter database datafile '' offline drop;
>
> 5) Alter database open

Comment: Is there any impact of other tablespace or database?

Answer (score 3):

If your datafile is held **inside a PDB**.
You will have to follow the next commands :

```
SHUTDOWN ABORT
STARTUP
ALTER PLUGGABLE DATABASE $MyPDB OPEN;
```

On this last command it should fail with an ORA-01110 error.
And if you try `ALTER DATABASE DATAFILE $datafileNumber OFFLINE DROP;`
You will encounter an ORA-01516.

This is because you are trying to DROP a datafile on the CDB instead of the PDB.

To do this properly, you have to modify the session to target PDB :

```
ALTER SESSION SET CONTAINER=$MyPDB;
```

Now you can drop the datafile and open the database :

```
ALTER DATABASE DATAFILE $datafileNumber OFFLINE DROP;
ALTER PLUGGABLE DATABASE $MyPDB OPEN;
```

### References

https://blogs.oracle.com/robertgfreeman/pdb-recovery-your-pdb-wont-open-because-a-datafile-is-missing

Comment: Thank you. "ALTER SESSION SET CONTAINER=" was what I was missing

Answer (score 0):

try to recover the datafile , identefy the name of the tablespace

```
select tablespace_name from dba_data_files where file_id =  8;
```

change the status of the tablespace to offline , so you can run the RMAN(recovery manager)

```
alter tablespace test offline immediate;
```

after that you have to run the RMAN to recovery the file.. for more info how to do that check this read this more about RMAN [Burleson](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_rman_copy_command_tips.htm)